# Magento 2 Custom Product type is missing "Configurations" button

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I'm creating a custom product type. I want it to function almost exactly like a Configurable Product. I am able to create a new product type, but it is missing the "Configurations" button in the admin panel which allows me to create variations.

Can anyone help me add the "Configurations" functionality to this product type?

Here's what's been done so far:

**Vendor/Module/etc/product_types.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="custom_product_type_code" label="Custom Product Type Label" modelInstance="Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type">
    </type>
    <composableTypes>
        <type name="custom_product_type_code" />
    </composableTypes>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/Model/Product/Type.php**

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Product;

class Type extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable
{
    const TYPE_ID = 'custom_product_type_code';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function deleteTypeSpecificData(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        // method intentionally empty
    }
}
```

**Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php**

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        //associate these attributes with new product type
        $fieldList = [
            'price',
            'special_price',
            'special_from_date',
            'special_to_date',
            'minimal_price',
            'cost',
            'tier_price',
            'weight',
        ];

        // make these attributes applicable to new product type
        foreach ($fieldList as $field) {
            $applyTo = explode(
                ',',
                $eavSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $field, 'apply_to')
            );
            if (!in_array(\Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_ID, $applyTo)) {
                $applyTo[] = \Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_ID;
                $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                    $field,
                    'apply_to',
                    implode(',', $applyTo)
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty old, but I faced the same issue. Here is how I did it:

1. Create file `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`
2. Paste this content:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\BaseAllowedProductTypes" type="Magento\Catalog\Ui\AllowedProductTypes">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="productTypes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_product_type_code" xsi:type="string">custom_product_type_code</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```